# Joomla 1.6 backend admin area blank

Tags: joomla

For some reason, when I log into my joomla 1.6 backend, it is now empty, displaying only a logout button. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I just went through the same problem but on J!1.7.3. There may be many, many reasons but please check using just URL if you can see for example:

- **[YourDomainHere]/administrator/index.php?option=com_content** or
- **[YourDomainHere]/administrator/index.php?option=com_modules**

If content is listing and you're missing just Admin-menu and sub-navigation in back-end --> this means you messed-up with access levels and viewing access.

If you can't see content listing - ignore the rest of this post :-)

...with access levels and viewing access. To check that, try entering **[YourDomainHere]/administrator/index.php?option=com_users&view=levels** and enter each position in the list. Joomla backend navigation module usually has Access set to Special, so focus on this one. When enter Special - manager, author and super administrator should be ticked. If everything empty in any from the list - this is your issue :)

You need to add manager, author and super administrator to your Special access level. Obviously you can't see Save button, so you need to use database. [wrrr :) sounds scary?] Not a big deal, just go there using for example phpMyAdmin and find _viewlevels table. In there just edit Special and add [6,2,8] values to set up manager, author, super.....

Update database. Try to log-in one more time (close browser and clean cache before).

I hope if this wasn't helpful for you, will be for somebody else.

p.s. There may be a way of 'saving' changes in you joomla access levels with URL. Then you don't need to go to DB .. but I don't know if this is feasible at all :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I wonder if there is a way to save through the url with some kind of action like, action=save or something, so that it is not mandatory to use the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check the rewrite of `htaccess` and the `$mosConfig_absolute_path` variable in `config.php`

Comment: I posted my config.php file here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610102/joomla-admin-backend-not-showing-up

Comment: Can you take a look at it, see above

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the Bluestork Template (admin template) has some security issues. In my case there were some missing files in the template folder **/administrator/templates/bluestork/** that caused the administrator screen to appear blank. I've copied a clean version of the template in the bluestork folder and after that I was able to see the backend admin area.

I've removed the bluestork templates entirely for now, which seems to be the best option. Joomla installs 2.5.8, 2.5.6, 2.5.2, 1.7.0, 1.6.3 are affected. The Blustork Template is a target for hacks with old Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

this happening becoz of admin user lost his permissions. see below article to fix this issue

http://www.codentalk.com/joomla-admin-showing-blank-page/