# joomla admin backend not showing up

Tags: joomla

joomla 1.6 ....when I login to administrator nothing shows up. this happened a few months back, cannot remember how it was fixed. Not sure what causes it, or how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is a problem with [Joomla session management](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2205995) and a [common php issue](http://amiworks.co.in/talk/the-white-screen-of-death/).

You need to first find the error, then fix it.

To identify the error try in configuration.php:

```
public $debug = '1';
```

And add/or this to .htaccess

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 2048
```

Once you determine the error, post or Google.

Comment: was able to change debug to 1. Didnt see anything odd. Cant figure out how to post the .htaccess code? Where? How?

Comment: Use FTP and go into the Joomla directory, open the file .htaccess if it's there, if not create one or rename htaccess.txt

Also what Joomla version are you using?

Comment: Figured it out, had to go to mysql user database, and change session to "0". Didnt log me out correctly.

Comment: Yep. It's sessions usually. Glad you got it!